# Multiple IF Tenure Statements in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am having trouble using multiple if statements in excel.

I'm trying to show different tenure brackets using the below but it says there are issues with the formula. Can anyone help please?

```
=IF([@[Tenure at LFA]]>2,"0-2 Years", IF([@[Tenure at LFA]]>4,"2-4 Years")), IF([@Tenure at LFA]>6,"4-6 Years"),"6+Years")
```

Comment: This is much easier with a lookup table btw, using `XLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` or `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Sorry - how would I build the VLOOKUP for example to take into account below 2 years for example?

Comment: and `IF()` takes three parameters. It should look like `IF(param1, param2, param3)`. If you nest an `If()` inside of that it will look like `IF(param1, IF(param1, param2, param3), param3)`. So each `if()` has three parameters inside parantheses. Yours looks like `IF(param1, IF(param1, param2)), IF (param1, param2), param???)` I can't even figure out what it's trying to do.